# Why is expectation for binomial distributions linear (intuitively)?

Tags: binomial-distribution

In the post by André Nicolas, in this [stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226237/expected-value-of-a-binomial-distribution), he writes that the expectation is a linear operator on events. This I can not understand, what exactly is intuitive explanation of expectation being linear? or, maybe some motivation to describe it as something linear.

Comment: Expectation is basically an integral, and integration is linear.

Comment: reading that statement gave me a heart attack. From what I know binomial distribution for finite number of trials is a discrete thing???!

Comment: From one hand Mathematical expectation in discrete case is also linear and on another hand we can consider discrete case as some  Stieltjes integral.

Comment: In the discrete case you can consider expectation as a summation instead of an integral if you like, and summation is a linear operator.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080030/linearity-of-expectations-why-does-it-hold-intuitively-even-when-the-r-v-s-are -- the question itself tries to give an intuition why the binomial distribution in particular has linearity of expectation, and the answers generalize to other discrete distributions.